# Stacked Bar Chart: Changing appearance of entire bar?

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I am using achartengine in my Android app to display a stacked bar chart (something similar to [this](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/SalesStackedBarChart.java)). I use the `ChartFactory.getBarChartView` to get a `GraphicalView` object that I then place in my layout.

**My objective is to provide touch feedback to the user when one of the stacked bars is touched by the user.** I intend to do this by changing some of the UI properties (probably color) of the bar that the user touched. However, I want to designate the *entire stacked bar* as touched. This is as opposed to designating just the selected section of the bar.

Taking the SalesStackedBarChart example from the demo, I want to designate the entire bar for, say, March as selected (not just the section for March 2008).

I already know how to set up `onClickListener` on the `GraphicalView` object and to use the `getCurrentSeriesAndPoint()` method. However, using this approach, I have been able to only designate the same section on *all* bars as selected. For example, the 2008 sections on all 12 bars are highlighted.

**Question:**

> How do I change the appearance of all sections in a single stacked bar?

Here's my code. It works as designed (i.e, sets the selected section on all 12 bars to gray), but this is not what I want.

```
mGraph.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mGraph.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
                if (seriesSelection == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "No chart element was long pressed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false; // no chart element was long pressed, so let
                                  // something
                    // else handle the event
                } else {
                    SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer = mMultiRenderer.getSeriesRendererAt(seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex());

                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Chart element in series index "
                            + seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex() + " data point index "
                            + seriesSelection.getPointIndex() + " was long pressed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    renderer.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);                      
                    return true; 
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the color of a series will change the colors of all bars in that series.

One potential solution would be to create an extra series containing only the bars you want to highlight as selected. Quite tricky.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was hoping to be able to manipulate the bar itself (which I guess boils down to manipulating an `XYSeries` rather than a `Renderer`). Guess I'll have to think of other ways to give the user touch feedback.